# Creating rethinkdb cluster

Tags: rethinkdb

I'm writing an automation script that supposed to create 4 instances in AWS and deploy rethinkdb cluster on them without any human interaction. According to the documentation I need to either use `--join` parameter on command line or put `join` statements in configuration file. However, what I don't understand is if I need to specify `join` only once in order to create the cluster or every time I restart any of the cluster nodes?

My current understanding is that I only need to issue it once, the cluster configuration is somehow stored in metadata and next time I can just start rethinkdb without `--join` parameter and it will reconnect to the rest of the cluster on its own. But when would I need the `join` option in the configuration file then?

If this is true then do I need to start rethinkdb with `--join` option in my script then shut it down and then start again without `--join`? Is this the right way to do it or there are better alternatives?

Comment: I would appreciate some explanation from downvoters.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but this is pretty easy to test on your dev machine. Just run the second instance with `-o 1 -d /some/other/path -j localhost:29015`, then halt it, then run it again without the join and see what happens in the admin interfaces on ports 8080 and 8081.

Comment: @analytik, yes this is what I ended up doing but I was hoping for a quick answer here :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're right that on subsequent restarting, you don't need to specify `--join` from command line, it will discover the cluster and attempt to re-connect. Part of cluster state is store in system table `server_config`.

Even if you wiped out the data directory on a this node, it may still be able to form cluster because other nodes may have information about that node, and will attempt to connect to it. But if no other node store information about this particular server, or when this particular node is restarted and have a new IP address for some reason, and its data directory is wiped as well, this time, the cluster doesn't know about it(with new IP address).

So, I'll always specifiing `--join`. It doesn't hurt. And it helps in worst case to make the new node be able to join cluster again.